# Record Video/Take Picture switch in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-capture, image

So i got a iphone app that is a button and when you pressed it i want the camera view to pop up and i want to give the user a choice to take a picture or a video like in the default camera app the one switch thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something called 'UIImagePickerController'

```
-(void) getPhoto:(id) sender {
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
} else {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

This method is the what would be called when you press your button(s), what i am doing here is I have two buttons, choosePhotoBtn, and takePhotoBtn, the both link to the same method.

If the button that was pressed (the sender) is choosePhotoBtn, then UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum is set as the UIImagePickerController's source type.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
bannerImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

These two methods are delegate methods. They get called when the modelViewController holding the UIImagePickerController is dismissed.

I would recommend this site, as it has a brilliant tutorial on how to use these functions.

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/

This is where i learnt how to use these classes, it seems like the site has had a wordpress comment attack on it at the moment, and firefox is blocking it for me, but if u can get to the page. Its a great resource.